# Converting Lat Long to Usable values in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, latitude-longitude

I am using both QGIS 1.8 and 2.0.  So either is helpful.

A client has given me locations of trial pits but i cannot load them into QGIS no matter how hard i try.

For example, 50°24.711 North 7°25.529 West.  The site is near Enniskillen Co. Fermanagh Northern Ireland.  Any system i can find to convert degrees minutes and seconds will not allow 24.711, and seconds only go to 60.

Comment: you need to convert it from degree-decimal minutes (different from degree/minute/second) into decimal degrees.  if you have this data in an excel table, you have to divide the 24.711 by 60, and add that decimal value to the degree value for 50.41185, and use that value instead. you can use a formula in excel if you have lots of values to change, or manually if there are only a few

Comment: The location you were given, maps to the middle of the Celtic Sea.

Comment: How have you been given these locations? In a spreadsheet, text file, written on a scrap of paper? Any chance we could have a sample of the source?

Comment: In order to convert deg/min second to decimal degrees I do it with the following formula in a spreadsheet

Comment: In order to convert deg/min second to decimal degrees I do it with the following formula in a spreadsheet deg+(min/60)+(sec/3600). for western longitudes and southern latitudes I do as follows -1*(deg+(min/60)+(sec/3600)). Usually I isolate the results by copy and paste values add a column with a name/identifier and save as a csv comma delimited file. Then you can use the "add delimited text layer" plug in to load the points in qgis. Hope it helps

Comment: Any of my previous attemps landed the points in the middle of the sea or in england somewhere.  I was given the data literally on a scrap of paper, supposedly recorded by the digger driver via a total station.

Comment: TDavis, i think you have answered my question and possed me with another....what system did they use to record them as it appears to be incorrect! If you wish to ad your comment as an answer i will accept it.

Comment: Gerardo...same goes for you...put it as an answer....if your name was Geraldo...now that would be better!

Answer (score 1):

As [commented by @TDavis](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/109030/converting-lat-long-to-usable-values-in-qgis#comment153264_109030):

> you need to convert it from degree-decimal minutes (different from
>   degree/minute/second) into decimal degrees. if you have this data in
>   an excel table, you have to divide the 24.711 by 60, and add that
>   decimal value to the degree value for 50.41185, and use that value
>   instead. you can use a formula in excel if you have lots of values to
>   change, or manually if there are only a few